# knockout variable not defined - scoping issue?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have the following code:

```
var ObjectViewModel = function (testObject) {
    //debugger;
    var self = this;
    self.id = testSet.id;
    self.details = testOject.details;
    self.children = ko.observableArray(testObject.children);
    self.childCount = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.children().length;
    });

    self.addObject = function () {
        //debugger;
        // Pending UI
        // Call API here
        // On success, complete
        self.children.push(dummyObject);
        self.childToAdd("");
    }.bind(self);
    }
    / etc
```

However in childCount, this.children() is undefined.  I'm trying to let the view show the length of the children array in real-time, so as the user adds/removes items, the count is updated.  Any idea why this isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass what the value of `this` should be when the function is executed  to the computed function with the last parameter:

```
this.childCount = ko.computed(function() {
    return this.children().length;
}, this);
```

You could also store a reference to `this` outside of the computed:

```
var self = this;
this.childCount = ko.computed(function () {
    return self.children().length;
});
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew.  When I do this, childCount is always returning 0, and doesn't update when the array changes.  Does the usage of "computed" look ok there?

Comment: @JakeP: Looks ok to me--how are you adding and removing items to the observable array?

Comment: @JakeP: Is it self.cards or self.children?

Comment: ah, self.children - I renamed some variables for simplicity

Comment: @JakeP: Hmm, Probably need to see all of it to know why it's not working. I have a simple example here: http://jsfiddle.net/CCNtR/15/ that works fine, could it be the bindings in your HTML?

Comment: Dude, spot on.  Sorry for the ambiguity there.  It's working now :)